# JSON displayed to tableview

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, objectmapper

I want to use AlamofireObjectMapper for the first time to parse a json response in swift. 
I mapped it like this:

```
class ModelCurrency:  Mappable {

 var success   : Bool?
    var terms     : String?
    var privacy   : String?
    var timestamp : CGFloat?
    var source    : String?
    var quotes    : [Quotes]?

    init() {}

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

         success<-map["success"]
         terms<-map["terms"]
         privacy<-map["privacy"]
         timestamp<-map["timestamp"]
         source<-map["source"]
         quotes<-map["quotes"]

        print("It json\(terms)")
    }
}

class Quotes : Mappable {

    var name : String?
    var val : CGFloat?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name<-map["name"]
        val<-map["val"]
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
 var arrayTable = [String]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let URL = "http://www.apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=ad847a0a855c0647590df2b818923025"

        Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ModelCurrency>) in

            let currency = response.result.value!;

            for quotes in currency.quotes! {


                self.arrayTable.append(quotes.name!)

            }
        }

    }


   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return  5}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arrayTable.count   }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel?.text = self.arrayTable[indexPath.row]


        return cell
        }
```

I want array quotes displayed in tableview. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to [reload](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) table view after you updated the data source `arrayTable`:

```
...
for quotes in currency.quotes! {
  self.arrayTable.append(quotes.name!)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
...
```

Besides, you don't need to call `super.viewDidLoad()` twice.